# How to RDP from one Azure VM to another with AzureAD Auth?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-vm

I have multiple VM's on Azure, all enabled for AAD Authentication.

From my PC, I can RDP into any of them using my AAD creds successfully.

However, if I RDP into one of them, and then from there try to RDP into a different one, it fails with a generic "your credentials did not work" message.

Any ideas why this doesn't work? I would like to use one of them as my daily workstation VM, and be able to RDP into the others as needed.

Comment: This seems like a networking problem.  You should run a network trace and figure out if your credentials are being verified.

Answer (score 0):

For the error **"Your Credentials Did Not Work"**

Please check if below are the reasons for getting the error,

- **Windows Policy**: Maybe Windows Security Policy is preventing non-admin users from signing in.
- **Username change**: If you rename your user account of other VM, it doesn't get change for the RDP connection

To know more in detail please refer this link: [Your Credentials Did not Work in Remote Desktop](https://appuals.com/fix-your-credentials-did-not-work-in-remote-desktop/)

> **To troubleshoot the error, please follow below steps,**

- Try running Network Adapter Troubleshooter
- Try changing the network profile from public to private
- Try changing account Username
- Try editing windows security policy
- Try using the group policy editor

To know how to perform all these in detail please refer [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/your-credentials-did-not-work-in-remote-desktop-on-windows-10).